# I need your help for an error I encounter in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have an application and I created a legin and logout page... and when I click on my application's logout button, I get an error like this " Null check operator used on a null value"*and when I point to the error, it tells me  [1] :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0uJ8.pngentrez

> import 'dart:async';
> import 'dart:convert';
> import 'dart:async';
> import 'dart:convert';
> import 'dart:math';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:http/http.dart';
> import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
>
> ```
> import '../db/db_auth_shared_preference.dart';
> import '../network/app_urls.dart';
> import '../models/auth.dart';
>
> enum Status {
> notLoggedIn,
> loggedIn,
> authenticating,
> loggedOut,
>
> notReet,
> reseted,
> resetting
> }
>
> //Help display the logs
> var logger = Logger();
>
> class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
> Auth? _auth;
>
> Auth get auth => _auth!;
>
> void setAuth(Auth auth) {
> _auth = auth;
> notifyListeners();
> }
>
> bool isAuth() {
> if (_auth == null || auth.token == '') {
> return false;
> }
> return true;
> }
>
> // Time before the token expires
> Timer? _authTimer;
>
> DateTime? _expiryDate;
> String? username;
> String? password;
>
> // Set the status of the user to Not Logged In at the start     of the app
> Status _status = Status.notLoggedIn;
>
> Status get status => _status;
>
> // Change the status of the user
> set status(Status value) {
> _status = value;
> notifyListeners();
> }
>
> // Log In the user
> Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(String email, String password) async {
> Map<String, Object> results;
>
> final Map<String, dynamic> loginData = {
>   'email': email,
>   'password': password
>  };
>
> status = Status.authenticating;
> logger.d("--- Authentication ---");
>
> try {
> Response response = await post(
> Uri.parse(
> "${AppUrl.login}?    username=${loginData['email']}&password=${loginData['password']}"
> ```
>
> ),
> );
>
> ```
> logger.d('Login response : ${response.statusCode}');
>
>  // The Request Succeded
>  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
>  final Map<String, dynamic> responseData =
>  json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
>
>  var requestStatus = responseData["status"];
>
>  if (requestStatus != 0) {
>  status = Status.notLoggedIn;
>  results = {'status': false, 'message': "La Connexion a échoué"};
>  } else {
>  // Get the status code of the request
>  Map<String, dynamic> authData =    responseData["utilisateurJson"];
>  logger.d(authData);
>
>  _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(seconds: 3500));
>
>   //store user shared pref
>   Auth authUser = Auth.fromMap(authData,
>   timeToExpire: _expiryDate,
>   username: loginData['email'],
>   password: loginData['password']);
>
>   _expiryDate = authUser.expiryDate;
>   logger.wtf(_expiryDate);
>   //clear session data
>   AuthPreferences().removeAuth();
>
>   //store User session
>   AuthPreferences().saveAuth(authUser);
>   setAuth(authUser);
>   status = Status.loggedIn;
>
>   username = loginData["email"];
>   password = loginData["password"];
>
>   results = {
>   'status': true,
>   'message': 'Successful login',
>   'auth': authUser,
>   };
>   autoLogOut();
>   }
>   } else {
>   status = Status.notLoggedIn;
>   results = {'status': false, 'message': 'La Connexion a échoué'};
>   }
>   return results;
>   } catch (e) {
>   logger.e(e);
>   status = Status.notLoggedIn;
>   results = {
>   'status': false,
>   'message': "La Connexion avec le serveur a échoué"
>   };
>   return results;
> }   }
>
>  void autoLogOut() {
>  if (_authTimer != null) {
>  _authTimer!.cancel();
>  }
>  final timeToExpiry =        _expiryDate!.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds;
>  _authTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: timeToExpiry),
>  () async => await login(username!, password!));
>  }
>
> // Log Out the User
> void logOut() {
> logger.d("--- User Logging Out ---");
> AuthPreferences().removeAuth();
> status = Status.loggedOut;
> _expiryDate = null;
> _auth = null;
>
> logger.d("--- User Logged Out ---");
>  }
>
> Future<Auth?> tryAutoLogin() async {
> final authSession = await AuthPreferences().getAuth();
> if (authSession == null) {
> return null;
> }
> logger.d("The expiry time is : ${authSession.expiryDate}");
> if (authSession.expiryDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
> login(authSession.username, authSession.password);
> return authSession;
> }
>
> _expiryDate = authSession.expiryDate;
> setAuth(authSession);
> logger.d("SETTING THE USER");
> autoLogOut();
> return authSession;
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you post your question in English, and consider including minimal snippet example code that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: You are getting null user on `_auth!`, try checking below post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error Explanation:** Bang operator(!) means that in flutter, when you use this operator, you are completely sure that variable is not going to be null in any case.
There are two ways to resolve it -

1. Use **if** conditional to confirm that variable is not null
2. Use **null-aware** or **if-null** operator **??** like

```
Auth get auth => _auth ?? Auth();
```

Since you didn't provide any error logs; based on attached image and as your cursor on line no 29, `_auth` variable  is `null`. So before using **`!`** make sure your variable is not `null`.

Comment: ok ok i see

I try and I will come back
Thanks a lot

Comment: please i tried your solution but the problem is still there should i remove the "_auth!"

Comment: please attach error logs for better understanding of the problem

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi2V5.png

Comment: As it is displaying in your attached logs image, I think that after logout you are trying to get **Auth**, which is generating said error.

Comment: It's exactly that